# How to refer to another Spring based project using local Maven repository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-3

There are two projects. Exporting (which exports some functionality), and the Importing (using the aforementioned exporting functionality).

`mvn clean install` from the exporting project and then adding that project as a `dependancy` in the importing project should theoretically make the functionality available to the second.

But when it comes to Spring Boot projects, this seem to not work.

In the screenshot below, the 1 refer to how the import works fine, as the local library is found by Maven.
However, when you try to refer to the package, it doesn't quite work straight out as it should.

Any tips?

Two projects are on GitHub: https://github.com/madukan/SpringMavenLocalRepoExample

[image]

Comment: Looks like more a problem with your IDE instead of wrong steps with maven, I mean, you follow the correct steps to build a local maven and local import, should work, try to restart your IDE and clean cache.

Comment: Well, I would've thought the same unless `mvn clean compile` from importing project didn't give the same error as the IDE. I tried exporting and importing modules (JPMS) without luck too.

Comment: But compile and install are different, when you install you put your build in your repository .m2, when you compile, just make the target and all the stuff just for your project. So when you did the `mvn clean install` should work perfectly, try to clean cache and restart the IDE

Comment: And if not work after restart and clean cache, try doing a `mvn clean install -o` last argument its to compile with the current downloaded library, so maybe you have a policy in your settings which make you necessary update all the dependencies including the local ones

Comment: I don't have a settings.xml, nor cache clearing in the IDE helped. From the exporting-project I did `mvn clean install -o`. No issues. Then did ` mvn compile` from the importing-project. I get: `[8,1] package com.springmaven.exportingproject does not exist. [22,29] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ExportedFuntionality
[ERROR]   location: class com.springmaven.importingproject.ImportingprojectApplication`

Comment: So the issue is re-producible even from Maven. Keeping the IDE (IntelliJ, in this case) out of the equation.

Comment: The shared Github project https://github.com/madukan/SpringMavenLocalRepoExample is quite a basic Spring project demonstrating the issue, if you would like to have a peek.

Comment: Thanks for your attempts to solve this issue btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, by default it is configured to produce executable jars which are "applications", however you need a "library", something like following should help:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>repackage</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- custom classifier for executable jars -->
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please note, after that executable jar name will be something like `xxxx-exec.jar`

Another, actually more preferable, option is to split your project into two submodules: "library" and "application"

Comment: Did you try applying this solution to the shared Github project? Even though the answer sound quite promising I don't see it working at the moment. I used your code without the `<configuration>` node as I don't have any use for a executable jar in the exporting project.

Comment: Thanks for your attempts to solve this issue btw.

Comment: `I don't have any use for a executable jar in the exporting project` - you actually *have*, try to call "Show effective POM" from IntelliJ (select `exportingproject` in maven window, than right click) and check what configuration of `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is actually applied to your project.

Comment: What I meant is my Jar is a library. Not an executable. Something is not right when it is a Spring Boot project. If I remove all Spring and make it a direct library, then it becomes available this way. Will keep on trying..

Comment: Okay found the difference. The part that say `<classifier>exec</classifier>` is the missing piece of the puzzle for me. Thank you! Here's my reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-dependency, Thanks to IntelliJ team too.

Comment: So that config block looks like: 
`<configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
</configuration>
`

Comment: I marked @Andrey's response as the answer.